# Why does installing to /usr/bin automatically install to /usr/bin/X11?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, directory-structure

I am using the command:

```
install ./prog /usr/bin
```

to copy the program to the `/usr/bin` directory. Doing this automatically installs the prog to `/usr/bin/X11`. Deleting from `/usr/bin` also automatically removes it from `/usr/bin/X11`. Does my Linux Mint automatically do this? What is the reason for this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This because `/usr/bin/X11` is a symlink to `/usr/bin` (the dot at the end means the same directory as the link is in ):

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/X11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 May  5  2013 /usr/bin/X11 -> .
```

If you browse or `cd` to this directory, you are really just looking at `/usr/bin`.